# Decrease .mat file size

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of .txt files with sizes from 100MB to 300MB and I want to transfer all the data that is in them to .mat files. The data is mostly numbers and I am looking to make the storage space as small as possible. Right now what I've done is read the data in the .txt files, put them in a struct and then save it using a v7.3 compression scheme, but each variable then comes out to be almost 9 GB. Would anyone have an idea about how I can make this better ?

Comment: “Put them in a struct”. Please provide details on how you store the data. This is likely where your problem is.

Comment: 300MB to 9GB is worse than if you converted every character into a double-precision representation of its ASCII value, without any conversion to actual numbers and with no compression. The .mat size is almost certainly a symptom of unintentional treatment of the data before it was saved.

Answer (score 2):

You can save to MAT file `v7` as noted in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html):

> Version 7.3 MAT-files use an HDF5 based format that requires some overhead storage to describe the contents of the file. For cell arrays, structure arrays, or other containers that can store heterogeneous data types, Version 7.3 MAT-files are sometimes larger than Version 7 MAT-files.